# Reverse url with multiple optional params

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have following URL in URLconf:

```
url(r'^events(/((?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<year>\d{4}))?/(?P<company_uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})?)?$',
    'events',
    name='events'),
```

and views.py:

```
@login_required
def events(request, day=None, month=None, year=None, company_uuid=None):
    today = now()
    if company_uuid:
        return HttpResponse(company_uuid)
```

day, month, year and company_uuid are optional parameters.
So, I can navigate to

- /events
- /events/13062013
- /events/13062013/28b68080-d336-11e2-b53f-001e681fda9d

But somewhere in template, I want to use reverse url and build link like:

```
<a class="btn" href="{% url 'events' company_uuid=company.uuid %}">Show all company events</a>
```

to show all company events without specyfing date.

All I get is error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /companies
Reverse for 'events' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'company_uuid': u'28b68080-d336-11e2-b53f-001e681fda9d'}' not found.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Since your urls isn't designed to handle a url that looks like this `events/companyuid/` as it relies on dates as well, the `/13062013/` part. Redesigning your URL pattern will make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
url(
    r'^events/(?:(?P<year>\d{4})/)?(?:(?P<month>\d{2})/)?(?:(?P<day>\d{2})/)?(?:(?P<company_uuid>[a-f0-9\-]{36})/)?$',
    'events',
    name='events'),
```

I have done following changes.

- Simplified the `company_uuid` pattern, you can switch back to yours if you want
- When you have day, month, year you should display URL more nicely e.g `events/2013/12/01/` instead of `events/20131201/`
- Changed the hierarchy to `year -> month -> day` instead of `day -> month -> year`
- Following patterns will match:

  - `events/{year}/`
  - `events/{year}/{month}/`
  - `events/{year}/{month}/{day}/`
  - `events/{year}/{month}/{day}/{company_uuid}/`
  - And many more
- In Template now you can do

  - For this URL and in general also you should always use named groups
  - `{% url 'events' year=2013 %}`
  - `{% url 'events' year=2013 month=6 %}`
  - `{% url 'events' year=2013 month=6 day=13 %}`
  - `{% url 'events' year=2013 month=6 day=13 company_uuid='28b68080-d336-11e2-b53f-001e681fda9d' %}`
  - `{% url 'events' company_uuid='28b68080-d336-11e2-b53f-001e681fda9d' %}`
  - And many more

Comment: In your example, month and year contains slash. Example:
events/2013/06/14

day is 14 (correct)
month is 06/ (incorrent)
year is 2013/ (incorrent)